# How do I pass a parameter to this Google ReCaptcha function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I am having an issue getting the `count` parameter to pass into the `verifyCallback` in the following piece of code:

```
var CaptchaCallback = function () {
  console.log('CaptchaCallback run');
  var count = 0;

  $('.g-recaptcha').each(function (index, el) {
    grecaptcha.render(el, { 
      'sitekey': 'xxx', 
      'callback': verifyCallback(count) 
    });
    count++;
  });
};
```

If I remove the parameter everything works as it should, only the parameter can't be passed for an essential part of the function.

If I add the parameter the function runs straight away without waiting for the ReCaptcha to be verified.

I want to be able to pass the parameter and then have the function run when the ReCaptcha is verified.

Here is the function that the parameter is passed to if it helps:

```
function verifyCallback(formNumber) {
  //var formNumber = 1;
  console.log('verifyCallback');
  $('#submitBtn_' + formNumber).prop('disabled', false);
  console.log('#submitBtn_' + formNumber);
}
```

Edit: When I use the parameter it doesn't bring the count through, it brings back the response from Google...

Thank-you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you're calling the `verifyCallback` function immediately and assigning the returned value of that function to the `callback` property.

To fix this, wrap the function call in an anonymous function which is then provided as a reference to the `callback`. Also note that you can use the `index` value from the `each()` handler instead of manually maintaining the `count` variable. Using this method will also mean that you don't need to use a closure to keep the `count` value in scope of the current iteration. Try this:

```
var CaptchaCallback = function () {
  console.log('CaptchaCallback run');

  $('.g-recaptcha').each(function (index, el) {
    grecaptcha.render(el, { 
      sitekey: 'xxx', 
      callback: function() {
        verifyCallback(index) 
      });
    });
    count++;
  });
};
```